# Not possible to locate an element using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating an application using selenium webdriver with java. I'm facing the issue that cannot locate an element in a page.

HTML Code:

```
<main id="main-section">
<div class="main-content">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="EventsController as eventcntrlr">
<div class="full-banner">
<section class="dashboard-tournaments">
<div class="" ng-show="eventcntrlr.noTournamentsFound==2" style="">
<div class="dt-title" ng-show="eventcntrlr.upcomingTournamentsCount !=0" style="">
<div class="dtslider" ng-show="eventcntrlr.upcomingTournamentsCount !=0" style="">
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 810px; margin: 0px auto;">
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 0px;">
<ul class="bxslider upcomingSliderClass no-slide" ng-class="{'no-slide':eventcntrlr.upcomingTournamentsCount<eventcntrlr.SlideCount}" style="display: block; width: 415%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<!-- ngRepeat: allupcoming in eventcntrlr.upcomingTournaments -->
<li class="upcomingSpanHeight ng-scope" ng-repeat="allupcoming in eventcntrlr.upcomingTournaments" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 400px; margin-right: 10px;">
<span class="ratio-width upcoming-spanWidth" style="height: 205px;"/>
<div class="dtslider-block">
<div class`enter code here`="dtslider-content">
<img ng-src="../../category/music.jpg" alt="slienter code hereder" src="../../category/music.jpg"/>
<div class="hover-contents">
```

Code:

```
public void playTournament() throws InterruptedException, BiffException,IOException {

        int successRowNumber = 7;
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]"));
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='emailtxt']"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, successRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement password =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordtxt']");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, successRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement continueButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[3]/a/span ");
        continueButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        WebElement events = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='events_li']/a");
        events.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        input(properties.getProperty("VAR_GROUPPINDETAILS"));
        int successfulTournamentCreationRowNumber = 12;
        WebElement tournamentSearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_searchname']");
        tournamentSearch.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, successfulTournamentCreationRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement findEvent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[5]/a");
        findEvent.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement Tournaments = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/div");
        Tournaments.click();
```

Got the error msg: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible.
Issue is for the element "Tournaments "

Comment: Firstly you'd probably need to change Tournaments to tournaments. Also selenium tells you, that element is not visible. Do you see it on the page at that time?

Comment: Yes, the element is visible on the page

Comment: Can you point to the tournaments element in html? Think it worth to come up with better locator.

Comment: Please take a minute to properly indent the HTML so that it's easier to read and understand. Also make sure you've included all the relevant HTML and indicate which element you are trying to click. As levgen said, you probably need a better locator. Using an XPath that long is asking for trouble.